# Spring - beans getting initialize twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am aware about the tale of two context in spring. I understand that there are two context - one for `ContextLoaderListener` and another for `DispatcherServlet`.

I am trying to use all java config for the project and remove the web.xml file completely. So I have use `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` class. But I am facing the problem in that. When I start the server, I can see the beans are created twice. Can you help me understand, what am I doing wrong.

As you can see I tried different annotation for RootConfig file so that it ignores the Config referenced in EnableWebMvc class and few other combinations but it always scans those classes and initiates the bean. (see the log line `viewResolver called` and `datasource bean creation` are printed twice)

Here are project details:

**logs**:

```
Jan 11, 2018 12:20:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5220 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jan 11 00:21:37 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.nikdroid.poc.config.RootConfig]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
datasource bean creation
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nikdroid.poc.controller.HomeController.home()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jan 11 00:21:37 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
viewResolver called
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12563 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 11 00:21:49 IST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.nikdroid.poc.config.WebConfig]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
datasource bean creation
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nikdroid.poc.controller.HomeController.home()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Jan 11 00:21:49 IST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
viewResolver called
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 2643 ms
Jan 11, 2018 12:22:08 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 71461 ms
```

And
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

```
package com.nikdroid.poc.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

**WebConfig**

```
package com.nikdroid.poc.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
/*@ComponentScan("com.nikdroid.poc")*/
/*@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={ControllerMarker.class, ServiceMarker.class, DaoMarker.class})*/
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nikdroid.poc",
excludeFilters = {
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
            value = {
                WebConfig.class
            })
})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        System.out.println("viewResolver called");
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        //resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

}
```

**RootConfig**

```
package com.nikdroid.poc.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.nikdroid"},
excludeFilters={
    @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)
})
/*@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={ControllerMarker.class, ServiceMarker.class, DaoMarker.class},
    excludeFilters={
        @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)
    })*/
/*@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nikdroid.poc",
excludeFilters = {
    @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
            value = {
                    com.nikdroid.poc.config.WebConfig.class
            })
})*/
/*@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nikdroid.poc", 
excludeFilters = @Filter(type=FilterType.REGEX,pattern="com\\.nikdroid\\.poc\\.config\\..*")) */

/*@ComponentScan("com.nikdroid.poc")*/
public class RootConfig {

}
```

**JPAConfig**

```
package com.nikdroid.poc.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.nikdroid.poc" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class JPAConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        System.out.println("datasource bean creation");
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        ds.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        ds.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        ds.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return ds;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sfb = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
      sfb.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.nikdroid.poc" });//TODO  find alternate
      sfb.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
      return sfb;
    }


    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple component scans which all load (in the end) the same configuration. Remove the component scan from the `JpaConfig` and also fix your component scan on the `WebConfig` that should exclude the `RootConfig`. You are probably better of excluding all `@Configuration` classes from auto detection and `@Import` the needed configuration for the config you want.

Comment: Thanks removing `@ComponentScan` has fixed duplicate logs of view resolver. But I still have the duplicate logs of `datasource bean creation`. I have applied filter on the `RootConfig` `@ComponentScan` which basically must exclude scanning and discovery of `WebConfig` class, but that is still not happening. You can see the different combination that I have tried...I have commented it out in the code.

Since `RootConfig` is loaded before `WebConfig`, I have applied restriction on `RootConfig` and not `Webconfig`...

Comment: Your understanding of what happens is of/wrong. You also need to exclude what you don't want to load in the `WebConfig` (in this case the `RootConfig` else it will be loaded twice.

Comment: where as if I use `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.nikdroid.poc", excludeFilters = {@Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {com.nikdroid.poc.config.RootConfig.class})})` on `WebConfig` along with removing `@ComponentScan` from `JPAConfig`, now there are no duplicate code lines. So thanks what you said seems to have worked.